# Processing, How to set volume in Minim?

Tags: processing

```
if (key == 'k')
{
    player = minim.loadFile("abc.wav");
    player.amp(volume[levelOfVolume]);
}
```

I try to use `Minim` to play an audio, and alsp i want to set a key which can change the volume, however, the volume function is not working

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? Note that this should **not** be your full sketch. It should be an example sketch that demonstrates just the problem you're stuck on. This will make it much easier to help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try [setGain()](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/audioplayer_method_setgain.html) or [shiftGain()](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/audioplayer_method_shiftgain.html), as described in the links^.